# Angular 5 with Firebase - Service returns undefined in component before service completes

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular-services

I have a service that is supposed to return some stats on a character.

The stats are calculated based on the character level.

The parent component is calling the service which makes the call to Firebase to find the level and then subscribes to see the value and do the calculations but the parent sees that currentStats is still undefined. I feel like I need to tell the parent component to wait and possibly solve this with lifecycle hook but that seems kind of sloppy and I am wondering what the best practices for something like this could be. Any pointers would be welcome. Code below:

Parent TS:

```
constructor(private statsService: StatsService...) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.statsService.currentStats.subscribe(
        statsSource => (this.statsSource = statsSource)
    );

}
```

Service:

```
// level service returns the character level
constructor(private levelService: levelService) {
    // Services do not utilize the oninit lifecycle, so I wrote a function to act like one.
    // I saw this as a suggestion in researching but this does not seem optimal.
    this.init();
}

levelObservable: any;
level: number;
characterSp: number;
characterVitality: number;
statsSource: any;
currentStats: any;

init(){
    this.levelObservable = this.levelService.getLevel();
    this.levelObservable.subscribe(level => {
        this.level = level;
        this.characterSp = this.level * 2;
        this.characterVitality = this.level * 6;
        this.statsSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
            spellPoints: this.characterSp,
            actionDice: 3,
            vitality: this.characterVitality,
            wounds: 10 
        });
        this.currentStats = this.statsSource.asObservable();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the Observable straight away if you don't want it to be undefined. Try that

```
// level service returns the character level
constructor(private levelService: levelService) {
    // Services do not utilize the oninit lifecycle, so I wrote a function to act like one.
    // I saw this as a suggestion in researching but this does not seem optimal.
    this.init();
}

levelObservable: any;
level: number;
characterSp: number;
characterVitality: number;
statsSource : Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
currentStats: Observable<any> = this.statsSource.asObservable();

init(){
    this.levelObservable = this.levelService.getLevel();
    this.levelObservable.subscribe(level => {
        this.level = level;
        this.characterSp = this.level * 2;
        this.characterVitality = this.level * 6;
        this.statsSource.next({
            spellPoints: this.characterSp,
            actionDice: 3,
            vitality: this.characterVitality,
            wounds: 10 
        });
    });
```

Edit: example on how to use async pipe

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private statsService: StatsService...) {}

statsSource$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.statsSource$ = this.statsService.currentStats;

}
```

**component.html**

```
<span>{{(statsSource$ |async)?.vitaliy}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks! So this kind of works. The values are set and updated as expected but it makes my screen freeze up for a second and I'm seeing a "Cannot read property 'vitality' of undefined" error about 10 times on refresh so I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong here. Should I just do all the calculations in the service and pass those instead of just keeping the service to a minimum?

Comment: You probably need to use the async pipe to avoid the undefined error. I updated the answer